# Can Cosmos DB read data from File Blob or Csv or Json file at a batch size?

Tags: .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am currently researching around reading data using cosmos db, basically our current approach is using a .Net Core C# application with Cosmos DB SDK to read entire data from a file blob or csv or json file, and then use the for loop, one by one pulling its information from cosmos db and compare/insert/update, this somehow feels inefficient.

We're curious if cosmos DB could perform the ability to read a bunch of data (let's say a batch size of 5000 records) from file blob or csv or json file and similar like SQL server, do a *bulk insert* or *merge statement* within the cosmos DB directly? Basically the goal is not doing same operation one by one for each item interacting with cosmos DB.

I've noticed and researched in BulkExecutor as well, the BulkUpdate looks like a more straightforward way of directly updating an item without considering if it should update. In my case for example, if I have 1000 items, only 300 items' properties got changed, so I'll just need to update those 300 items without updating the irrelevant remaining 700 items as well. Basically I need to find out a way to have Cosmos DB do the data compare as in a collection, not inside a loop and focus on each single item, it could either perform a update or output a collection that I can use for later updating as well.

Would the (.Net + SDK) application be able to perform that or would a cosmos DB stored procedure could handle similar job? Any other Azure tool is welcome as well!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [Cosmos DB Bulk Executor library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-overview)

It is designed to operate using millions of records in bulk and it is very efficient.

You can find the .NET documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-dot-net)

Comment: Thank you! I'm interested more in the **update** part, the _BulkUpdate_ looks like a more straightforward way of directly updating an item **without considering if it should update**, for example, if I have 1000 items, only 300 items' properties got changed, so I'll just need to update those 300 items without updating the irrelevant remaining 700 items.Basically I need to find out a way to have Cosmos DB do the data compare as in a collection, not inside a loop and focus on each single item.